# Algebra of matrices

Tags: matrices

How to find the possible square roots of the two rowed unit matrix I ?

I took a matrix like this
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} a& b \\ c & -a \end{pmatrix}$$
  I couldn't figure out why  $b$ and $c$ were not equal to $0$ when $(a+d)=0$ in a previous post that I checked. Please explain everything from north to south  in detail.

Answer (score 5):

I assume that you want to find all two-by-two matrices, say $\bf M$, for which ${\bf M}^2 = {\bf I}$.

Write down a general two-by-two matrix, square it, set the result equal to $\bf I$, and solve the four simultaneous equations.

$${\bf M} := \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right)$$

$${\bf M}^2 = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a^2+bc & b(a+d) \\ c(a+d) & bc+d^2 \end{array}\right)$$

You need to solve $a^2+bc = bc+d^2 = 1$ and $b(a+d)=c(a+d)=0$ simultaneously.

The obvious place to start is $b(a+d)=c(a+d)=0$. This give different possibilities. Either $a+d = 0$, or $b=c=0$. You need to follow these two cases through.

If $b=c=0$ then $a^2+bc = 1$ and $bc+d^2 = 1$ become $a^2=1$ and $d^2=1$, and so $a=\pm 1$ and $d = \pm$ independently (there are four possible solutions).

If $a+d=0$ then $d=-a$ and $a^2+bc = 1$ and $bc+d^2 = 1$ reduce to the single equation $a^2+bc = 1$. This splinters into lots of different cases:

If $1-bc \ge 0$ then $a = \pm \sqrt{1-bc}$.

If $c \neq 0$ then $b = (1-a^2)/c$.

If $b \neq 0$ then $c = (1-a^2)/b$.

Comment: No downvote any more; but you should learn to use `\mathbf{M}` instead of `{\bf M}`, a syntax that's been deprecated in LaTeX for 20 years.  Also `\begin{pmatrix}...\end{pmatrix}` is better than `\left(\begin{array}{cc}...\end{array}\right)` (at least simpler to input).

Comment: You don't need to set matrices in bold at all.

Comment: @anomaly ISO/IEC regulations for technical writing prescribe using bold italic for matrices.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the advice. I will use pmatrix in future because, as you say, it's simpler to input. But for that very reason I'll still use {\bf M}.

Comment: Why should mathematicians care in the slightest about ISO/IEC regulations on technical writing?

Comment: @anomaly Why should you care in the slightest if I put matrices in bold or not?

Comment: Your three cases for $a^2+bc=1$ are not disjoint. It would be sufficient to say: **Either** choose $a$ and $b\ne 0$, and then set $c=\frac{1-a^2}b$, **or** $b=0$, $c$ arbitrary and $a=\pm1$.

Comment: For the same reason I'd suggest that you don't need to put arrows on the top of vectors, hats on the top of linear operators, and so on. Write whatever you like, but ISO regulations are a very silly reason to follow a particular convention.

Comment: @HenningMakholm True, but they do give a (possibly overlapping) parametrisation of the set of matrices whose square is the identity.

Comment: @anomaly I'm sorry it offends you, but I quite like it. Sorry :-(

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices <=== Pauli Matrices $\sigma_{i}^{2} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ for $i = x, y, z$, etc...